# How to read and process Open Document Spreadsheet (*.ods) files with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ods, opendocument

I am able to read and process *.xlsx files using an input element of type file and the library exceljs. Also see example code below.

Unfortunately, exceljs does not seem to support open document spreadsheet files *.ods. (The `worksheet` is undefined).

=> How can I read and process *.ods files with javascript?

https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs

https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/716

```
static async readFile(file){
        
        await this.__initializeExcel();
       
        const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        await workbook.xlsx.load(file);

        const worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0];

        var data = [];
        const numberOfRows = worksheet.rowCount;
        for (let rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {
          const row = worksheet.getRow(rowIndex);
          const rowValues = row.values;
          data.push(rowValues);
          rowValues.shift();          
        }

        return data;
    }
```

*Related*

- https://github.com/webodf/WebODF
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-odf

Comment: Have you looked at [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs)?

Comment: Not yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Brian I managed to read and process *.ods files with sheetjs/xlsx:

https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

```
npm install xlsx --save
```

If you use script tags for import, please make sure to import `xlsx.full.min.js` instead of `xlsx.min.js`. Otherwise you'll get an error `Cannot find file [Content_Types].xml in zip`.

```
static async readOdsFile(file){
        
        await this.__initializeXlsx();  //imports xlsx.full.min.js by script tag
      
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = event =>  {
                try{
                    var result = reader.result;
                    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(result);
                    var workbook = Xlsx.read(dataArray, {type: 'array'});

                    const firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];  
                    const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
                    const data = Xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{header:1});                
                resolve(data); 
                } catch(error){
                    reject(error);
                }
               
            };

            try{                
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            } catch (error){
                reject(error);
            }
        }) ;  
       
    }
```